# How can I keep horizontal element alignment inside an expanding list item?

Tags: html, css, menu, styling

I have been tasked with styling a website, where I have encountered a hurdle regarding the horizontal alignment of elements inside list items.

I have replicated the structure of the menu in question with [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vqaymke0/).

I want to know how I can keep the position of the green divs (as shown from the start) when I expand the menu, using the button in the fiddle. I need them to keep horizontal alignment with the first `<a>` element in their respective `<li>` element, when the submenus are displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this for example:

```html
<html>
  <script>
    function clickFunction(){
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");
      for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].classList.toggle("display-sublist");
      }
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    ul{
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    ul li{
      width: 100%;
      background-color: blue;
    }
    .submenu{
      display: none;
    }
    .display-sublist{
      display: block;
    }
    ul li a{
      width: 95%;
      background-color: red;
    }
    .main-test {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      width: 90%;
    }
    .cancel-test{
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: green;
      float: right;
      width: 10%;
    }
    .expand-button{
      clear: both;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="main-test" href="#">Something</a>
        <a class="cancel-test">x</div>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub-Something</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub-Something</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub-Something</a>
          </li>
        </ul>       
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="main-test"href="#">Something</a>
        <a class="cancel-test">x</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Sub-Something</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Sub-Something</a>
            </li>
          </ul>         
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Something</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Something</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  <button onclick="clickFunction()" class="expand-button">Expand</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. Great job. I have to mention for the sake of brevity, that it was the exact order of the elements - the divs following the a tags - that made this solution work.